# MS Bot blob storage not able to find the current user

Tags: botframework, azure-blob-storage

We are trying to persist user information in Blob Storage. We can write, verify the file exists fine, but when we try and access it in a dialog from `context` the user is not found.

In our initial connection endpoint, check if user exists, if not, we create one:

```js
await storage.write({
  [`directline/users/${userId}`]: {
    [USER_STATE_PROPERTY]: {
      customData: {},
    }
  }
});
```

Record is in blob storage. The blob storage we have is like so:

```js
import {
  AutoSaveStateMiddleware,
  BotFrameworkAdapter,
  UserState,
  ConversationState
 } from 'botbuilder';
import { log } from './logger';
import { BlobStorage } from 'botbuilder-azure';
import Bot from '../bot';

const storage = new BlobStorage({
  containerName: BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME,
  storageAccountOrConnectionString: BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING
});

const userState = new UserState(storage);
const conversationState = new ConversationState(storage);
const botInstance = new Bot(conversationState, userState);

const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
  appId: APP_ID,
  appPassword: APP_PASSWORD,
});

adapter.use(new AutoSaveStateMiddleware(conversationState, userState));

...
```

However, when a conversation starts we cannot find the current user:

```js
class Bot {
  private conversationState;
  private userState;
  private dialogState;
  private dialogs;
  private userProfile;

  constructor(conversationState: ConversationState, userState) {
    this.conversationState = conversationState;
    this.userState = userState;
    this.dialogState = this.conversationState.createProperty(DIALOG_STATE_PROPERTY);
    this.userProfile = this.userState.createProperty(USER_STATE_PROPERTY);
    this.dialogs = new DialogSet(this.dialogState);
  }

  public async onTurn(turnContext) {
    const { type, membersAdded, recipient } = turnContext.activity;

    if (type === ActivityTypes.Message || type === ActivityTypes.Event) {
      const user = await this.userProfile.get(turnContext, {});
      // user is always {}
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using the SaveChanges method to check the changes to the property in the state cache and then write those changes to storage?

Answer (score 0):

So bad. Error was missing trailing `/` that MS appends to each id